# How to use php variable in ajax url?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to use a PHP variable in AJAX url. How can I achieve this?

**my.php**

```
function displayRecords() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=Ami&password=74153&mobile=$number&message=$message&sender=INFORM&type=3",
        data: "show="+numRecords+"&pagenum="+pageNum,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { 
            $('#content').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24" style=" padding-left:469px;">');
        },
        success: function(html) {    
            $("#results").html( html );
        }
    });
}
<?php
$message="hi"
$number=8888888888;
?>
```

Here I want to use these PHP variables  in AJAX url

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Move the php block **above** the javascript function.

Comment: Though having your api credentials in your javascript for all to see seems a particularly bad idea

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Comment: One down vote for including API credentials in the question. Don't be dumb again. @anil kumar

Comment: Here this is not my original api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below :-

```
<?php
    $message="hi"
    $number=8888888888;
    ?>

function displayRecords() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=Ami&password=74153&mobile=<?php echo $number; ?>&message=<?php echo $message; ?>&sender=INFORM&type=3",
        data: "show="+numRecords+"&pagenum="+pageNum,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { 
            $('#content').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24" style=" padding-left:469px;">');
        },
        success: function(html) {    
            $("#results").html( html );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: **Moderator Note** I've removed all the unnecessary comments here. If you feel the need to discuss these issues, then take it to chat.  I see no evidence that this was a copied answer so stop arguing about it.

Answer (score 4):

move your php code above js and add php code in js to get your php variables

```
<?php
$message="hi"
$number=8888888888;
?>
<script>
function displayRecords() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=Ami&password=74153&mobile=<?php echo $number;?>&message=<?php echo $message;?>&sender=INFORM&type=3",
        data: "show="+numRecords+"&pagenum="+pageNum,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { 
            $('#content').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24" style=" padding-left:469px;">');
        },
        success: function(html) {    
            $("#results").html( html );
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh... we have replied same :)

Comment: @Khushboo yeah you need to upvote if you got correct rather another answer

Comment: A little fight in you. I like that. @anil kumar

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
function displayRecords() {
var numRecords = '<?php echo hi; ?>';
var pageNum = '<?php echo 8888888888; ?>';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.bulksmsgateway.in/sendmessage.php?user=Ami&password=74153&mobile=
    <?php echo    $number;?>&message=<?php echo $message;?>&sender=INFORM&type=3",
    data: "show="+numRecords+"&pagenum="+pageNum,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () { 
        $('#content').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24" style="
         padding-   left:469px;">');
    },
    success: function(html) {    
        $("#results").html( html );
    }
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is $message and other php var values?